# Gem for flexible object initialization

Tags: ruby

I have implemented a class allowing to initialize itself in different ways.

First way: object is created, attributes are set later.

```
object = MyClass.new
object.name = 'Object'
```

Second way: hash of attributes are passed to object constructor.

```
MyClass.new(:name => 'Object')
```

Third way: Block is passed to object constructor.

```
MyClass.new do |object|
  object.name = 'Object'
end
```

I was inspired by [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/model.rb#L66)

I've been thinking that it's so trivial that somebody has probably implemented it as a separate gem or maybe there is some built-in Ruby solution?

Comment: There's the old [constructor gem](http://atomicobjectrb.rubyforge.org/constructor/), which is different-but-the-same. OpenStruct already allows this, but might not always fit in to your app's object model (and has at least a couple other caveats). Part of it is that since an implementation is just a few lines nobody's bothered turning it into a gem (that I've ever seen, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this (not really a gem but still)...

https://github.com/guerilla-di/tracksperanto/blob/master/lib/tracksperanto/block_init.rb

You will get the default constructor when you include that module into a class.

It's reaaaally tiny so you could just drop it into your project and be done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if this is what you are looking for, but you might be interested in the [injection](https://github.com/atomicobject/injection) gem.